# Why this SemaphoreSlim waits indefinitely?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(Test);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static async Task Test()
        {
            var semahore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
            Console.WriteLine("before");
            await semahore.WaitAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("after");
        }
    }
}
```

I create a semaphore with limit 1 and current value of 0. It should allow 1 thread to pass, right? Why it doesn't in this example?

Comment: First parameter in constructor is : "The initial number of requests for the semaphore that can be granted concurrently". In your example it's set to 0

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I create a semaphore with limit 1 and current value of 0. It should allow 1 thread to pass, right?

No - the current value is 0, exactly as you wrote.

Semaphore values count *down* when they're awaited - the count is effectively "the number of tokens available to be acquired". From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim):

> The count is decremented each time a thread enters the semaphore, and incremented each time a thread releases the semaphore. To enter the semaphore, a thread calls one of the `Wait` or `WaitAsync` overloads. To release the semaphore, it calls one of the Release overloads. When the count reaches zero, subsequent calls to one of the Wait methods block until other threads release the semaphore.

If you want to create a semaphore which will immediately allow one thread to wait for it and "pass", you should create it with an initial value of 1, not 0.